# Rails: How to initialize an object with the attributes in strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, hashmap

Probably been working on this too long, sloppy design, or both.  My issue is I have a model I wish to initialize.  The object has like 52 attributes, but I'm only setting a certain ~25 depending on which object I've just scanned.  When I scan an object I get the columns and match them up with a hash_map I've created.

**Example Hash Map**

This just matches the scanned text to their respective attribute name.

```
hash_map = {"Pizza."=>"pizza_pie","PastaBowl"=>"pasta_bowl","tacos"=>"hard_shell_taco","IceCream"=>"ice_cream","PopTarts"=>"pop_tart"}
```

**What I want to do**

```
menu = RestaurantMenu.new(pizza_pie => var1, pasta_bowl => var2, ...)
```

My only problem is in my code at the moment I have this...

```
t.rows.each do |r|
  for i in 0..r.length-1
     #hash_map[t.combined_columns[i]] => r.[i]
     puts "#{hash_map["#{t.combined_columns[i]}"]} => #{r[i]}"
  end
end
```

the `puts` line displays what I want, but unsure how to get that in my app properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is several ways to fix this:

```
hash_map = {"Pizza."=>"pizza_pie","PastaBowl"=>"pasta_bowl","tacos"=>"hard_shell_taco","IceCream"=>"ice_cream","PopTarts"=>"pop_tart"}

attributes.each do |attribute, element|
  message.send((attribute + '=').to_sym, hash_map[element])
end
```

or like this:

```
class Example
  attr_reader :Pizza, :PastaBowl #...

  def initialize args
    args.each do |k, v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

for more details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680523/dry-ruby-initialization-with-hash-argument)

Comment: you should probably add an `if respond_to?("#{k}=")` to ensure you are trying to set an existing setter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following method:

```
attributes = Hash[]
attributes["restaurant"] = tmp_basic_info.name
attributes["menu_item"] = tmp_basic_info.item_name

t.rows.each do |r|
  for i in 0..r.length-1
     attributes["other"] = t.other_information
     attributes[hash_map[t.combined_columns[i]] = r[i]
  end
  row = ImportMenuItem.new(attributes)
  row.save
end
```