# Shortcut for setting initialize() args to attributes?

Tags: ruby

This is a common initializer pattern:

```
def initialize(title, val, type)
  @title, @val, @type = title, val, type
end
```

Is there a shortcut that is equivalent to "take every argument, create an attribute of the same name, and set the attribute equal to the argument's value"?

I'm looking for a gem-free solution.

Comment: Pretty good thread about that over here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680523/dry-ruby-initialization-with-hash-argument

Comment: @Jazzepi, it's an interesting thread, but only deals with hash arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do that.  One instance variable and an associated read/write accessor will be created for each of `initialize`'s parameters, with the variable having the same name, preceded by `@`, and each instance variable will be assigned the value of the associated parameter.

**Code**

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(< arbitrary parameters >)
    self.class.params.each { |v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{v}", instance_eval("#{v}")) }

    < other code >
  end

  @params = instance_method(:initialize).parameters.map(&:last)
  @params.each { |p| instance_eval("attr_accessor :#{p}") }

  class << self
    attr_reader :params
  end  

  < other code >     
end
```

**Example**

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    self.class.params.each { |v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{v}", instance_eval("#{v}")) }
  end

  @params = instance_method(:initialize).parameters.map(&:last)
  @params.each { |p| instance_eval("attr_accessor :#{p}") }

  class << self
    attr_reader :params
  end  
end

MyClass.methods(false)
  #=> [:params]
MyClass.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:a, :a=, :b, :b=, :c, :c=]

m = MyClass.new(1,2,3)
m.a #=> 1
m.b #=> 2
m.c #=> 3
m.a = 4
m.a #=> 4
```

**Explanation**

When class `MyClass` is parsed, the class instance variable `@params` is assigned an array whose elements are `initialize`'s parameters.  This is possible because the method `initialize` been created when the code beginning `@params = ...` is parsed.

The method [Method#parameters](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html#method-i-parameters) is used to obtain `initialize`'s parameters.  For the example above,

```
instance_method(:initialize).parameters
  #=> [[:req, :a], [:req, :b], [:req, :c]]
```

so

```
@params = instance_method(:initialize).parameters.map(&:last)
  #=> [:a, :b, :c]
```

We then create the read/write accessors:

```
@params.each { |p| instance_eval("attr_accessor :#{p}") }
```

and a read accessor for `@params`, for use by `initialize`:

```
class << self
  attr_reader :params
end
```

When an instance `my_class` of `MyClass` is created, the parameter values passed to `MyClass.new` are passed to `initialize`.  `initialize` then loops though the class instance variable `@params` and sets the value of each instance variable.  In this example,

```
MyClass.new(1,2,3)
```

invokes `initialize(a,b,c)` where

```
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3
```

We have:

```
params = self.class.params
  #=> [:a, :b, :c]

params.each { |v| instance_variable_set("@#{v}", instance_eval("#{v}")) }
```

For the first element of `params` (`:a`), this is:

```
instance_variable_set("@a", instance_eval(a) }
```

which is:

```
instance_variable_set("@a", 1 }
```

causing `@a` to be assigned `1`.

Note the accessor for `@params` is not essential:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@params).each { |v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{v}", instance_eval("#{v}")) }
  end

  @params = instance_method(:initialize).parameters.map(&:last)
  @params.each { |p| instance_eval("attr_accessor :#{p}") }
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You will lose the function to check against wrong arguments, but can do this:

```
def initialize(*args)
  @title, @val, @type = args
end
```

But if you are repeatedly doing this, then your code is not right. You should better redesign your API to take named arguments:

```
def initialize(title:, val:, type:)
  ...
end

WhateverClass.new(title: "foo", val: "bar", type: "baz")
```

Comment: simply simple and best

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Struct* as mentioned above or do it dynamically like:

```
class MyClass

  def initialize input
    input.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
    end
  end

end
```

Anyways If it's my code I'll go using Struct.

Answer (score 1):

I like to just use an args hash and send each attribute to the instance. However this will not create accessors for these attributes, so you will need to add these if they are desired.

```
def initialize(args)
  args.each do |method, value|
    self.send("#{method}=", value)
  end
end
```